# Lazy scopes in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

As we know, scopes starts load when calling. So this expression

```
articles = Article.published
articles.newest
```

gets 2 queries. Yes, we can do such this

```
articles = Article.published.newest
```

But what if I need conditions? If foo == bar than continue chain.

Comment: Can we see your Article model?  Generally speaking, queries should not be executed until you try to traverse the results or certain other method calls, like count.

Comment: Artcile is abstraction. Queries should be, but not scopes.

Comment: Scopes are the same.  They won't be executed immediately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are incorrect.  In your example, the two lines:

```
articles = Article.published
articles.newest
```

This will not generate two queries.  The reason that you are able to continue chaining is that these calls will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which will only execute a query on traversal or a select few other method calls, like count, sum, or other aggregation methods.

If you are looking at this from the console, it will appear that each line is generating a query.  This is because in the console, there is an implicit `inspect` call being called after every evaluation, which will generate a query.

Comment: A link to docs or source substantiating this claim would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Conditions in the same table?

```
@a = Article.where("published = true AND foo = bar").order("publishing_date desc").limit(1)
```

If you need eager loading with multiple tables, use the `includes(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do like below:

```
articles = foo == bar ? Article.published.newest : Article.published
```

Comment: It will 2 queries. But Articles.published.newes - one.

Comment: But if I have more than 2 scopes?